# Intents on implements View.onClickListener null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I have alot of buttons on my application and I'm trying to keep it tidy by setting a View.Onclicklistener inside of another class and then linking it back. But the problem I'm having is that if I setup any intents from this other class then my app crashes and I get a null object reference. any ideas as to why, because this can be any intent.

Example of one of the intents I'm trying to implement.

```
Button btnContacts = (Button)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btnContacts);

    btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final Uri uriContact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);
            startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);





        }
    });
```

Remember this is inside of another class I built which I then reference back to call the onclick listener e.g. btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new onClickListenerName);

Error message

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3942)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3889)
                                                                                  at thedeveloperslounge.projectr.AlarmListViewOnClick.AlarmText.AlarmContactNumber$1.onClick(AlarmContactNumber.java:83)

Comment: Please show the logcat. `promptsView` or `btnContacts` is null and that has nothing to do with the intent code

Comment: But for example if I apply a simple Toast to the same button then it works fine, its just when I'm apply an intent, also just fetching logcat

Comment: All I'm saying is that it's hard to know what the errors are without the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just for a update..

In order to fix the current problem I replaced the View.onClickListener completely with a DialogFragment which I can the implement my methods on. All my code for getting contact information is working great now.

ANSWER: BUILD A DIALOG FRAGMENT

Thanks